# What are these reflective surfaces?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

I've seen this in a few rooms now, but there are what I assume to be reflective surfaces in a these rooms. I've got quite a shard collection and I've tried each of them, but none of them seem to work here. What do you need to do to get past these areas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In true metroidvania fashion, you need a shard called Reflector Ray. It is gotten off of a boss, I believe it was named Bathin.